# Table background image top center using html - not css

Tags: html, css

I have a table (dim: 100px * 500px) with background image - 1px*10px.
I write the background code in css:

```
background:  white url(../Images/line.png) repeat-x scroll top center;
```

But I want to convert it to html code in the table tag not css code,
like:

```
<table bgcolor="#FFF" background=".....">
```

How can I convert this code to HTML?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @rSara Did any answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="background: white url(../Images/line.png) repeat-x scroll top center;">
```

If you want to style an element inline, just write the style attribute and the CSS properties into (like in this example).

You may need to adapt the path, if your CSS file is not located in the same place like your HTML document, and that's the first problem that occurs when you style elements inline.
It's better to do this via a CSS file, because your HTML markup becomes cleaner and it will be less  expensive to make changes to your layout.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use style in the tag. no css!

Comment: There are no HTML attributes to do this, except for `style`. What you can do, to center an image, is, to create an image (with Photoshop, GIMP etc.) with the tables width and height, and place your image to the center and use it as your new `line.png`. If you don't have any program for that, [pixlr](http://pixlr.com/editor/) is a nice choice.

Answer (score 0):

This is not good.

But :

```
<table background="http://yoursite/images/bg.png" width="500" height="500">
  <tr>
   <td>This is a test ...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But I want the image to be: repeat-x scroll top center

Comment: `<table>` doesn't have have a [`background`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/table) property.